# Substructure such that $\operatorname{cof}(\sup(B \cap \omega_m))= \omega_1$

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

Let $\mathcal{L}=\{\in, \preceq\}$. Let $\mathcal{A}=(V_\theta, \in)$ (where $\theta > \omega$) be an $\mathcal{L}$-structure which interprets $\preceq^\mathcal{A}$ by some fixed well-ordering on $V_\theta$.

> Does there exist an elementary substructure $\mathcal{B}$ of $\mathcal{A}$ satisfying the following: $\operatorname{cof}(\sup(B \cap \omega_m))= \omega_1$ for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$?

For each $S \subseteq V_\theta$, let $\mathcal{B}_S$ be the Skolem hull of $A$ in $\mathcal{A}'$. Observe each $\mathcal{B}_S$ is an elementary substructure of $\mathcal{A}$. Perhaps we form an elementary chain from some subcollection of these $\mathcal{B}_S$ structures and take the union, but what would work? And how would I be able to know it satisfies the property?

Comment: First, $(\mathcal B_S: S\in V_\theta)$ is not an elementary chain, that would be a linearly ordered (usually even wellordered) sequence of elementary substructures which is increasing w.r.t. $\subseteq$. Furthermore it is easy to see that $\mathcal B= V_\theta$ so this is not the substructure you are looking for. But defining an elementary chain and taking the union is the right idea

Comment: @AndreasLietz Thank you for catching this error. I have edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true (modulo the detail that I think you want $\theta\ge\omega_\omega$, not $\theta>\omega$, since only the former ensures $\omega_m\in \mathcal{A}$ for all $m\in\omega$).

Fix $\theta\ge\omega_\omega$. The proof breaks into two key facts, one in the **construction** stage and one in the **verification** stage. The latter is essentially trivial but it is worth highlighting.

The first key fact we use is the following:

> $(*)\quad$ Suppose $\mathcal{M}$ is a countable elementary substructure of $\mathcal{A}$ with underlying set $M$. Then there is a countable elementary substructure $\mathcal{M}'$ of $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\mathcal{M}\preccurlyeq\mathcal{M}'$ and $\sup(\mathcal{M}'\cap\omega_m)>\sup(\mathcal{M}\cap\omega_m)$ for all $m$.

*Proof*: just apply Lowenheim-Skolem to build a countable elementary substructure of $\mathcal{A}$ containing the countable set $M\cup\{\sup(M\cap\omega_m): m\in\omega\}$. (Note that for each $m$, $\sup(M\cap \omega_m)$ is a single ordinal, so this whole set is indeed countable.) $\quad\Box$

It may help to think of $(*)$ as addressing $\omega$-many requirements, one for each $\omega_m$ ($m<\omega$). We then apply $(*)$ $\omega_1$-many times to build the desired model $\mathcal{B}$ as the union of an elementary chain of countable models of length $\omega_1$: let $\mathcal{B}_0$ be any countable elementary submodel of $\mathcal{A}$, let $\mathcal{B}_\lambda=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda}\mathcal{B}_\alpha$ for $\lambda$ a countable limit, and let $\mathcal{B}_{\alpha+1}=\mathcal{B}_\alpha'$ per $(*)$ above. We then set $$\mathcal{B}=\bigcup_{\alpha<\omega_1}\mathcal{B}_\alpha.$$

Since $\mathcal{B}$ is constructed as the union of an elementary chain we have $\mathcal{B}\preccurlyeq\mathcal{A}$, so we just need to show that for each $m$ we have $cf(\mathcal{B}\cap\omega_m)=\omega_1$ as desired. This will follow from the following general observation:

> $(\dagger)\quad$ Suppose $\gamma$ is an uncountable ordinal and, for each $\eta<\omega_1$, $W_\eta$ is a countable sub-ordering of $\gamma$ such that $\delta<\eta<\omega_1\implies W_\delta\subset W_\eta$ and $\sup(W_\delta)<\sup(W_{\delta+1})$. Then $\bigcup_{\eta<\omega_1}W_\eta$, as a suborder of $\gamma$, has cofinality $\omega_1$ regardless of the specific $\gamma$ we started with.

(Note that the above is false if we replace "cofinality" with "ordertype" - this, together with the proof of $(\dagger)$ in the first place, is a good exercise.) To analyze $\mathcal{B}$ we apply $(\dagger)$ "$\omega$-many times," once for for each $m<\omega$: take $\gamma=\omega_m$ and $W_\eta=\mathcal{B}_\eta\cap\omega_m$ to get $cf(\mathcal{B}\cap\omega_m)=\omega_1$ as desired.

---

Incidentally, more complicated versions of this question - involving "big but locally small" models, which raise problems for greedy strategies like the above - raise the following interesting general question:

> Suppose $\mathcal{X}\preccurlyeq \mathcal{T}$ with $\mathcal{T}$ a "reasonably closed" transitive set (possibly + other structure). Under what conditions does $\mathcal{X}$ have a **top extension** $\mathcal{Y}$ with $\mathcal{X}\prec\mathcal{Y}\preccurlyeq\mathcal{T}$?

Here $\mathcal{Y}$ is a top extension of $\mathcal{X}$ if every element of $\mathcal{Y}\setminus\mathcal{X}$ has rank greater than that of every element of $\mathcal{X}$. E.g. nontrivial forcing extensions are **always** *end*-extensions but **never** *top*-extensions of their ground models. In a sense the question above is trivial ("exactly when there is some $a\in\mathcal{T}$ of high rank and some family of Skolem functions such that [stuff]"), but getting it to gel nicely can be rather messy if memory serves.

Comment: I think I understand the first part except one detail: how do we know $\sup(\mathcal{B}' \cap \omega_m) \neq \sup(\mathcal{B} \cap \omega_m)$? But the second part I don't get. What is $\gamma$ in this context? And is $W_\eta$ just $\mathcal{B}_\eta \cap \omega_m$ or is there a subtle difference?

Comment: @Pascal'sWager Re: the first part of your comment, remember we're building $\mathcal{B}'$ given $\mathcal{B}$. We just take $\mathcal{B}$, add - for each $m$ - an ordinal $\alpha_m\in(\sup(\mathcal{B}\cap\omega_m),\omega_m)$ - and then take an elementary substructure containing the resulting set. We trivially have $sup(\mathcal{B}'\cap\omega_m)>\alpha_m>\sup(\mathcal{B}\cap\omega_m)$ for each $m$. Think of this as building the desired model $\bigcup_{\alpha<\omega_1}\mathcal{B}_\alpha$ in $\omega_1$-many steps, where in each step we address $\omega$-many requirements (one for each $\omega_m$).

Comment: Re: the second part of your comment, the key point is applied (post-construction, if you like) once for each $m$, with $\gamma=\omega_m$ and $W_\eta=\mathcal{B}_\eta\cap\omega_m$, to get that $cf((\bigcup_{\alpha<\omega_1}\mathcal{B}_\alpha)\cap\omega_1)=\omega_1$ for each $m$.

Comment: @Pascal'sWager I've restructured my answer to be hopefully more transparent.

Comment: @Pascal'sWager Yup, fixed!

Comment: I also have another question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4389429/operatornamecf-supb-cap-omega-m-is-the-natural-numbers which starts with a similar setup. I bet a similar Lowenheim-Skolem argument (of course with a different construction) would do the trick