# $\operatorname{cf}(\sup(B \cap \omega_m))$ is the natural numbers

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, cardinals

Let $\mathcal{L}=\{\in, \preceq\}$. Let $\mathcal{A}=(V_\theta, \in)$ (where $\theta > \omega_\omega$) be an $\mathcal{L}$-structure which interprets $\preceq^\mathcal{A}$ by some fixed well-ordering on $V_\theta$.

> Does there exist an uncountable elementary substructure $\mathcal{B}$ of $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\operatorname{cf}(\sup(B \cap \omega_m))= \omega$ for all $m \in \omega \setminus\{0,1\}$?

Comment: As long as $\theta\geq\omega_\omega$, any countable elementary substructure of $\mathcal A$ works.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Sorry, I forgot to add a condition. We want $\mathcal{B}$ uncountable

Comment: As with your other question, I think you want $\theta\ge\omega_\omega$ instead of $\theta>\omega$ since otherwise we don't even have access to the $\omega_m$s.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar idea to what Noah did in the linked question will work:

> $(1)\quad$Let $S\subseteq\omega$ be any subset of $ω$, and let $\cal M$ (with domain $M$) be any elementary substructure of $\cal A$ such that $\sup(M\capω_m)≠ω_m$ for each $m∈S$, then there exists $\cal M'$(with domain $M'$) such that $\cal M\prec M'\prec A$, $|M|=|M'|$ and $\sup(M\capω_m)<\sup(M'\capω_m)<ω_m$ for each $m∈S$

The proof is basically the same as the one in the linked question: Use Lowenheim-Skolem the build an elementary substructure of $\cal A$ containing $M\cup\{\sup(M\capω_m)+1\}_{m∈S}$, call the resulting model $\cal M'$ and notice that $\sup(M'\capω_m)≥\sup(M\capω_m)+1>\sup(M\capω_m)$. $\quad\square$

Let $\cal M$ be any uncountable elementary substructure of $\cal A$ such that $\sup(M\capω_m)≠ω_m$ for each $m\in ω\setminus\{0,1\}$ (the existence of such elementary substructure is given by the linked question / downwards Lowenheim-Skolem theorem for any $\aleph_1$ elementary substructure), and constructure an $ω$-chain of models $\cal M=M_0\prec M_1 \prec\cdots\prec A$ from $(1)$ (we can use (1) indefinitely like this because of cardinality reasoning: each $\cal M_i$ is of cardinality $\aleph_1$, and $\operatorname{cof}(ω_m)=\aleph_m>\aleph_1$ for each $m\in\omega\setminus\{0,1\}$).

Let $\cal \bigcup M_i=N\prec A$ and notice that for given $m\in ω\setminus\{0,1\}$ we have $\operatorname{cof}(\sup(N\capω_m))$ is naturally $ω$ (as $\sup(N\capω_m)=\sup\{\sup(M_i\capω_m)\mid i\in\omega\}$).

---

Note that this $\cal N$ also have $\sup(N\capω)=ω$ and $\sup(N\capω_1)=\aleph_1$ (which is also their cofinality)

Comment: @Pascal'sWager any elementary substructure of $\cal A$ of cardinality $\aleph_1$ will work (and yes, that $\cal B$ is of cardinality $\aleph_1$, so it will work)

Comment: @Pascal'sWager Because it is union of $\aleph_1$ many sets, each contains at least 1 new element (also, $\aleph_1$ is regular, so if $\sup({\cal B}\capω_m)$ has cofinality of $\aleph_1$, then it contains at least $\aleph_1$ elements)

Comment: @Pascal'sWager only because of $M$ being of cardinality $\aleph_1$, if $\sup(M \cap \omega_m) =\omega_m$, then $|M \cap \omega_m|=\aleph_m$, so if $|M|=\aleph_1$ it will never happen for $m>1$

Comment: Why does $\sup\{\sup(M_i \cap \omega_m) | i \in \omega\}$ have cofinality $\omega$?

Comment: @Pascal'sWagerthay $\{\sup(M_i\cap \omega_m)\mid i\in\omega\}$ is countable, so pretty much by definition the supremum of that set has countable cofinality